# ASP.NET what will happen when I click submit btn in WebForm

Tags: asp.net

I am studying ASP.NET WebForm currently.
I want to know that if I make a onclick function(with server side script) on a button, I run and click it, what will happen behind the broswsers?
It seems that the response is so fast that it does not rerender everything in a webpage.
Or it will really send data to server side, processing, and send back the final html code for the browser to rerender?

Answer (score 1):

u can use debugging tool of visual studio 
or use third party software like fiddler,
this image will help u 
[image](http://cutesoft.net/data/asp-net-live-support.gif)

Comment: u can has cazing in sentences.

Answer (score 0):

It will cause a postback which is the same as a post request from the browser to the server. The server will then send a response to the post request that renders the page again.

Answer (score 0):

After button click a there will be a postback and then server well respond and whole page be rendered again. Refer this for [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)